# how to give static value of json object?

Tags: java, android

I want to give static value of json object ..But I am getting error in that .how I will assign that value.I try like that 
first way

```
  JSONObject jsonObj={"headcode":"s","destination":"Ardwick","origin":"Ardwick","time":"29:10:2014 09:52","turnNumber":"as","depot":"Barrow","conductorName":"as","devicePin":"123456.78.364813.8","noFirstClassImpact":"true","customersInvited":"false","customersUninvited":"false","customersLeft":"false"};
```

I am getting error change jsonobject to string array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work like that. See the other answers.

**You can also do it like this:**

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

jsonObject.put("destination", "ardwick");
jsonObject.put("depot", "barrow");
...
```

Then you can use `jsonObject.toString()` to get the values.

[Here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) you have the documentation for JSONObject.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
try {
     JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"headcode\":\"s\",\"destination\":\"Ardwick\",\"origin\":\"Ardwick\",\"time\":\"29:10:2014 09:52\",\"turnNumber\":\"as\",\"depot\":\"Barrow\",\"conductorName\":\"as\",\"devicePin\":\"123456.78.364813.8\",\"noFirstClassImpact\":\"true\",\"customersInvited\":\"false\",\"customersUninvited\":\"false\",\"customersLeft\":\"false\"}");
}catch (JSONException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a complete example to create a static JSONObject:

```
try {
            String myJson = "{\n" +
                    "    \"employees\": [\n" +
                    "        {\"first_name\": \"employeeFirstName1\", \"last_name\": \"employeeLastName1\"}, \n" +
                    "        {\"first_name\": \"employeeFirstName2\", \"last_name\": \"employeeLastName2\"}\n" +
                    "    ],\n" +
                    "    \"manager\": [\n" +
                    "        {\"first_name\": \"managerFirstName1\", \"last_name\": \"managerLastName1\"}, \n" +
                    "        {\"first_name\": \"managerFirstName2\", \"last_name\": \"managerLastName2\"}\n" +
                    "    ]\n" +
                    "}";
            //Log.i(CommonCode.TAG, myJson);
            JSONObject array = new JSONObject(myJson);
            JSONArray employees = array.getJSONArray("employees");
            JSONArray managers = array.getJSONArray("manager");

            Log.i("myDebug", "----- EMPLOYEES -----");

            for (int i = 0; i < employees.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject row = employees.getJSONObject(i);
                String firstName = row.getString("first_name");
                String lastName = row.getString("last_name");
                Log.i(CommonCode.TAG, "First name: " + firstName + ", Last name: " + lastName);
            }

            Log.i("myDebug", "----- MANAGERS -----");

            for(int i = 0; i< managers.length(); i++){
                JSONObject row = managers.getJSONObject(i);
                String firstName = row.getString("first_name");
                String lastName = row.getString("last_name");
                Log.i(CommonCode.TAG, "First name: " + firstName + ", Last name: " + lastName);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```